# How to insert a column to an existing table next to the last column using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

#### screenshot

[image: please see screenshot]

Hi I am a total noob at Excel VBA but how do I insert a column to a table that sums row by row. Because new columns need to be added to the table, I want the new column to be inserted in the table, essentially expanding the table but keep the new column within the table so the last column with the sum formula can include the new column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Wilson. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be waiting here for you ready to assist you finalize **your** code.

Comment: You might want to start by recording a macro: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b Afterwards, look at the recorded code and try to understand it. You can highlight key-words (blue words) in the code and press `F1` to get more information on them. Maybe that's already all you need: a recorded macro?

Answer (score 1):

The application I used this for is a little different than yours, but I this this will work all the same.

```
Dim LastCol As String

LastCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Count

Columns(LastCol - 0).EntireColumn.Insert

ActiveSheet.Columns(LastCol + 1).Cut
Columns(LastCol - 0).EntireColumn.Insert
```